# How to get all available entries of an EnumProperty?

Tags: python

As the questions already states? How do we get a list of all possible/available entries of an EnumProperty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enums are something Blender defines, which doesn't have a Python equivalent.
Therefor you need to use the RNA API. (See [API docs](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.EnumProperty.html#bpy.types.EnumProperty.enum_items))

Here is a function which returns possible values for an enum:

```
import bpy

def enum_members_from_type(rna_type, prop_str):
    prop = rna_type.bl_rna.properties[prop_str]
    return [e.identifier for e in prop.enum_items]


def enum_members_from_instance(rna_item, prop_str):
    return enum_members_from_type(type(rna_item), prop_str)


# Test the functions above:
enum = enum_members_from_instance(bpy.context.object, "rotation_mode")
print(enum)
# ['QUATERNION', 'XYZ', 'XZY', 'YXZ', 'YZX', 'ZXY', 'ZYX', 'AXIS_ANGLE']
```