# List the available render engines with python

Tags: python, luxrender-render-engine

so I want to get the list of available render engines, like in the error shown to check if luxcore is available, a workaround is to list the attribute names of `bpy.context.scene` if there's the luxcore string but I don't think this is neat

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "FOO" not found in ('BLENDER_EEVEE', 'BLENDER_WORKBENCH', 'CYCLES', 'LUXCORE')
```

This is the error thrown when you set a random string in `C.scene.render.engine = 'FOO'`

Comment: A possible answer is in this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58030/how-to-get-all-available-entries-of-an-enumproperty but I noticed something odd: when listing the enum entires for the render engine, only BLENDER_EEVEE is listed. When trying other enum properties in Blender, multiple values are listed as expected. Not sure why this is.

Comment: This is handled a bit strangely by Blender, the enum is initialized only with Eevee in the items and the others can't be access through the `bl_rna` properties with `enum_items`. For every render engine that is registered through Python inheriting from `bpy.types.RenderEngine` you can list them through `bpy.types.RenderEngine.__subclasses__()` and their respective `bl_idname`. This however does not include `BLENDER_EEVEE` and `BLENDER_WORKBENCH`.

Comment: As far as I can tell the enum is dynamically populated by `rna_RenderSettings_engine_itemf` in `rna_scene.c`.

Comment: For luxcore using `bpy.types.RenderEngine.__subclasses__()` lists luxcore and cycles, but the others not, maybe because blender_eevee and blender workbench are not addons, and listing enum properties (didn't know that, nice) should list the entries like in the error.

Comment: @Iszotic yes Eevee and the Workbench engine are considered internal (which they are) and therefore not inheriting the RenderEngine class, which is only the case for the Python add-ons. The `enum_items` only contains the value from the time of declaration, where only `BLENDER_EEVEE` is in it. It works when adding the `bpy.context.scene.render.engine` as `prop` in a panel, because that internally retrieves the items through the additional callback function `rna_RenderSettings_engine_itemf` which is not accessible through the Python API.