# Select CYCLES renderer in Blender from external IDE

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine

I'd like to control Blender from Spyder. Actually I can import bpy, add objects and perform complicated tasks, but I cannot select CYCLES as the redender engine with the ususal `bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'`:

Error: `TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "CYCLES" not found in ('BLENDER_EEVEE', 'BLENDER_WORKBENCH')`

This is the code of a simple script showing the error:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath="testBlend.blend")
```

Maybe the reason is suggested by Robert Gützkow here:
[List the available render engines with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154231/list-the-available-render-engines-with-python)

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Is cycles actually enabled? I mean in Preferences -> Add-ons?

Comment: Yes. If I open and use Blender normally, Cycles is enabled. If the [comment by Robert Gützkow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154231/list-the-available-render-engines-with-python) is right, the problem is quite subtle, and I'm looking for a workaround..